# Typescript + pouchdb remote login is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, pouchdb

I'm trying to login with remoteDb object with pouchDb and CouchDb on angular project, but getting an error **ERROR TypeError: this.remoteDatabase.login is not a function**. Below is the code snippet.

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PouchDBService {

  private isInstantiated: boolean;
  private localPouchDb: any;
  private remoteDatabase: any;
  private listener: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();


  public constructor() {
      if (!this.isInstantiated) {
          this.localPouchDb = new PouchDB('testdb');
          this.isInstantiated = true;
      }
      PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-authentication'));
  }

  public sync(remoteDbUrl: string) {
    this.remoteDatabase = new PouchDB(remoteDbUrl, {skip_setup: true});
    this.remoteDatabase.login('test_admin', 'test_password').then(function () {
      this.localPouchDb.sync(this.remoteDatabase, {
          live: true,
          retry: true
      }).on('change', change => {
          this.listener.emit(change);
      });
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Login error' + error);
    });
  }
```

I know this was a old issue and was fixed. But somehow I'm still seeing that error. Can someone please give some guidelines? 
Below are my package.json details.

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "0.0.0"
  "description": "test app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p ng:serve electron:serve",
    "build": "npm run electron:tsc && ng build",
    "build:dev": "npm run build -- -c dev",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- -c production",
    "ng:serve": "ng serve -o",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.3.1",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.6",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.6",
    "@angular/material": "^6.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.6",
    "@types/pouchdb": "^6.3.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "install": "^0.12.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "npm": "^6.1.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "pouchdb": "^7.0.0",
    "pouchdb-authentication": "^1.1.3",
    "pouchdb-browser": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.6",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^10.3.6",
    "codelyzer": "^4.4.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.1.0",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.10.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "wait-on": "^2.1.0",
    "webdriver-manager": "^12.0.6"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
import PouchAuth from 'pouchdb-authentication'

PouchDB.plugin(PouchAuth)
```

Same error is pointed out in Github and resolved there

https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication/issues/211#issuecomment-359470265